# Android , make gallery like images

Tags: android, android-fragments, gridview

I am working on a photos website management android application. I have created a fragment which shows the albums list in gridView and the album covers. I want to open the album when pressed and have another same format gridview and show the images in that albums in that gridview. Note that the album list in gridview is shown in fragment of a Navigation Drawer. So should I create a new activity or create a new fragment when i click on any album? Can someone give me the idea/guideline of how to achieve that. Thanks in advance. Currently i have set `onItemClickListner` of gridview to some custom message related to that album in `Toast`(it views the id of that album from MySQL).
Current view of gridview

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJZs0.png

Comment: Open an activity, It will be better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want that navigation drawer is still visible in the album-detail screen, then use a fragment. Generally, if you can use fragments, use always fragments. Use activities if only you cannot use fragments.

Comment: Thank you! I am doing with fragments.